# Accessing the argument which was passed to the callback function

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a simple class which implements the AsyncTask:

```
class Async( private val workload: () -> String,
             private val callback: ( httpResponse : String ) -> Unit
) : AsyncTask<String, String, String>()
{
    override fun doInBackground( vararg params: String? ): String?
    {
        return workload()
    }

    override fun onPostExecute( result: String )
    {
        callback( result ) // <-- argument being passed to the callback
        super.onPostExecute( result )
    }
}
```

I pass two arguments to this class, which are:

```
string workload() - function which takes long time to execute and returns a string
callback( string ) - the callback function to which I want to pass the value, which was returned by the workload()
```

Everything works fine, except that I can't seem to be able to find a way how to access the argument within the callback function:

```
Async(
    {
        workload()
    },
    {
        // how to "receive" the "test" string returned by the workload()? 
        Log.d( "myapp", ???_argumentPassedToCallback_??? );
    }
).execute( "" )


fun workload() : String
{
    Thread.sleep( 1000 )     
    return "test";
}
```

Any suggestions please? Thank you!

Comment: You may want to read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Async(
    {
        workload()
    },
    { response ->
      Log.d("foo", "The response is: $response")
    }
).execute( "" )
```